# Which is worse? One more db acess or one outdated value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**PROBLEM**

I'm running an application with AngularJS, Node JS, Express and MongoDB. I'm acessing MongoDB trought mongoose. My problem is that I have a lists of swords, each forged by someone. But, to access someone's profile, I need to use the ID of someone. The ID is unique. But I can't display the link as something link '352384b685326vyad6'. So, when someone create's a sword, I will store his or her name within the sword info.

To display a list of swords, for example, I could do something like this:

```
<div ng-repeat='sword in swords'>
  <p> Sword name: {{sword.name}} </p>
  <p> Author: <a href='#/user/{{sword.createdByID}}'> {{sword.createdByName}} </a> </p>
</div>
```

But, if the User changes his name, the sword will not update his creator name accordingly. What should I do? I have thought of some solutions, but I don't know which and if any could solve this in a good manner.

- When someone changes own name, I could make a POST request with the new username and the ID, updating all sword that has createdByID equals to user ID. But I see this too strange.

  ```
  SwordModel.find({ createdByID: req.body.id}, [...]);
  ```
- When loading the swords in the controller via GET request, make another GET request for each sword and update sword.username based on the sword.createdById.

  ```
  UserModel.findById(req.body.id), [...]);
  ```
- Forget UX and use ugly links.

I want to know how can I maintain the username of each sword updated without affecting too much my DB Thanks for any advice.

**MODELS - Just for reference.**

sword.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var SwordModel = mongoose.model('SwordModel', 
    {
        name: String,           //Sword's name
        createdById: String,    //ID of the user who created.
        createdByName: String   //Name of the user
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('SwordModel', SwordModel);
```

user.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var UserModel = mongoose.model('UserModel', 
    {
        name: String,           //Name of the user.
        ID: String              //ID of the user.
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('UserModel', UserModel);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we have less of a technical problem and more of a conceptual problem here.

## Constraints

I take it for granted that...

- users may change their usernames
- usernames are unique
- you only need to provide a link to a user, displayed by name

Furthermore, I will use plain JSON and MongoDB and trust that you can translate this to Mongoose.

## The solution

Albeit users can change their usernames, this is not going to happen often. The more common use case is that you need to link to a username. So we first need to find out how to efficiently deal with that use case.

Since you only need the name of the smith for a given sword, there is nothing wrong with a sword model like

```
{
  _id: new ObjectId(),
  name: "Libertas",
  smith: "Foobar"
}
```

to efficiently find "Foobar" in the users collection, we simply add an index here (if not already done):

```
db.users.createIndex({username:1}, {unique:true})
```

and your service can query efficiently by using

```
db.users.find({name: "Foobar"})
```

No need to save the `_id` of the user within the sword document, but still you can query for it efficiently.

Dealing with a change in the username is a rather rarely executed use case, so optimizing here does not make sense. However, if a user changes his or her username, your service can easily achieve that through

```
db.swords.update(
  { smith:"Foobar" },
  { $set:{ smith: "CoolNewUsername" },
  { multi: true, writeConcern: { w:1, j:true }
)
```

The last line of the above needs a little explanation. The `multi: true` option tells MongoDB to change *all* documents matching `{smith: "Foobar"}`, not only the first one found, that's easy to understand. But why to set the write concern to [journaled](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#journaled)? The first reason for it is that regardless of the write concern configured for the connection (which may even be [unacknowledged](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/#unacknowledged)), we need those changes to be durable. However, we usually do not need to have the changes to be propagated to more replica set members, so the chosen write concern gives you the best performance while still you can be sure that the changes were synced to a disk. If you need higher durability, of course you can set the write concern to [`{w:2}` or `{w:"majority"}`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/write-concern/#w-option).

## Advantages

1. For the most common use case of this relationship (displaying a link to the user who forged a given sword), all information needed to do this is included in the sword's document, preventing possibly unnecessary queries.
2. Still, the smith of a given sword can be queried efficiently if a user clicks said link.
3. Changing a users name is possible and can be achieved pretty efficiently and durable

## Disadvantages

The main disadvantage here is that you actually *have* to modify all affected swords when a user changes his or her username, whereas with a Mongoose reference that would be unnecessary. However, since this is a rare use case and using `populate` would result in the whole user document to be loaded where only the users name is needed, I see this disadvantage as negligible. Basically you are trading to cut down the queries needed for a common use case by half against the need for a manual update which occurs rather rarely.

I fail to see any other disadvantage.

Comment: thank you for the well explained answer. I will implement your solution. Good point about the rarely used use case of a user changing his name.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it by referencing the User inside Swords if you make use of Mongoose schema. 
After you make a reference to another schema you can use `populate` method to get the desired results.

Example (May be not exactly, but something similar to following) :

Sword Schema:

```
var swordSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    createdBy: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
```

Make model using the schema :

```
var swordModel =  mongoose.model('Sword', swordSchema);
```

Find what you are looking for using populate.

See full documentation for populate here - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

EDIT: note that I am recommending to keep user's name only in User model and just reference it.

Comment: thank you. You've showed one way of doing it and, most important, has shown me that I really need to study more about MongoDB as I did not knowa bout this populate method. Thank you.